# Sum columns of n rows in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

From table:

```
Name, Price, Tax
A, 1, 1
B, 2, 1
C, 9, 2
```

Calculate total based on formula:

```
Total:
Price A + Tax A +
Price B + Tax B +
Price C + Tax C
```

Which is: `1 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 9 + 2 = 16`

How to easly calculate such thing? In many-row tables doing so manually is very hard and ends up with somehing like `=$E5*F5+$E4*F4+$E3*F3+$E6*F6+$E7*F7+$E8*F8+$E9*F9+$E10*F10+$E11*F11+$E12*F12+$E13*F13` which is also hard to read and get around.

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT($E3:$E13,F3:F13)`

Comment: You want the sum of each row or the product, price + Tax

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a "Total" column in the fourth column (Column D).
2. In the row with Name A, in Column D, add a formula to sum JUST B2+C2
3. Click the lower right hand corner of cell D2 and DRAG down in order to copy the formula down and auomatically adjust for each cell.
4. Somewhere in your spreadsheet (in a blank cell), add a formula to SUM Column D.

You should never have to write an identical formula more than once in Excel.

Comment: You mean B2+C2 not B3

Comment: @yass Thanks, was trying to picture this in my head and type at the same time... didn't actually open Excel!

Answer (score 0):

Excel has multiple ways to do that; for example the so-called *Matrix-Formula*.

For your example, you would write `=SUM(E3:E13*F3:F13)`, and press CTRL+SHIFT+RET to store it as a matrix formula. Excel then 'loops' through the given ranges, and multiples them pairwise, and the SUM around it sums it all up.